# Error al obtener el plan de ejecución de un SP- SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, indices

Estoy ejecutando una Stored Procedure en sql server, pero cuando veo el plan de ejecución (CTRL+L) sale un mensaje indicando que un índice que creé para una tabla temporal no existe. 
A pesar que en el SP está textualmente la creación del índice

```
create index idx_#TmpAlmacenes  on #TmpAlmacenes (CodAlm)
```

¿A qué se debe esto?

Comment: Hola @Camilo. Por favor agrega más información sobre la pregunta: 1) estructura de la tabla, incluyendo sus índices, 2) el SP donde se emplea la tabla y el query específico donde debería usar el índice, 3) el resultado del plan de ejecución del SP.

Comment: creo que debes explicar brevemente que significa "hacerle el tuning" a un SP

Comment: Cambiare la pregunta,

Comment: Ayúdanos publicando todo el procedimiento.

Answer (score -1):

Crea el `indice` antes y despues ejecuta el `Procedimiento almacenado`.

O usa

```
ALTER PROCEDURE
```

En ingles esto se llama **deferred name resolution**.

Comment: pero el indice lo creo en una tabla temporal que se crea en el sp.